# Get output of external console app to RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, console

I used the VB.Net Shell() command to start a console app that I haven't created. I want to get the lines from that console to a RichTextBox in my form. It should be possible because I have seen many apps that do this. Please provide some information or any program that might help me. I tried to see if the external app creates log files, but it does not.

Here's how I started. What should I add, and where, to return the output?

```
Try
        writer.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
        writer.Close()
        Shell(CurDir() & "\yelloeye.exe .\new.demo")
Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: I guess you realized what I meant, I have edited the question title, please answer with some helpful information!

Comment: How about some code to show [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: FFS, done. Any help now?

Comment: It's highly unlikely you'll get any help at all with that attitude, chill out a bit and post the actual code you are having a problem with.

Comment: I am sorry for my attitude. I really got no code to show, I just shell a console app and I wan't to get that app's line to my RichTextBox.

Comment: Ok. Usually you'd do something like `myapp > c:\output.txt` from the command line, then you'd need to read this file back into your VB app and display the contents in your RTB.

Comment: But I don't own that console app tho, How I suppose to return a output? Thanks for you reply, it was really helpful. An example code will help more.

Comment: @TheBlueDog actually, you can use `Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True` then receive tbe output in an event.  Less circuitous and less chance of missed data because you get the output directly.

Comment: @Plutonix: I did not know that, you learn something new every day - I'll bank that for future reference ...

Comment: Thatnk guys, can you please answer this question with a code as i really don't understand? Thanks lot for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the `RedirectStandardOutput` property as mentioned by @Plutonix which will ping SO and display the results in a RichTextBox. Just replace the .exe name and arguments (if any) to suit your needs.

```
Private Sub ShellToRTB()
    Dim p As New Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.stackoverflow.com"
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    p.Start()
    RichTextBox1.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    p.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]